# What is the difference between standard location and significant location updates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

Both updates come from the same delegate method (locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:). [In Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10) they write that you can set desiredAccuracy and distanceFilter for standard location but they are silent about significant location updates accuracy and distance filter. What are those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significant location changes come from GSM / Wi-Fi location system, whereas standard location changes comes from GPS.

Significant location changes is much less accurate, but could meet your needs sometimes.
Moreover, signification location changes continue to run in background even after you app is being killed! So don't forget to stop it when quitting.

If you don't stop significant location changes, you're app is awoken on... significant location changes.

For such behavior, you could also check region monitoring, even if it's only available from iOS 4.

Comment: @Suz not sure about your edit, region monitoring will not wake up the phone on iPhone 3GS, as the `regionMonirotingAvailable` property will return false.

Comment: Thanks. But what about accuracy of significant changes? I tried setting desiredAccuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters and kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer - both return 1414. Does that mean significant update ignores that property?

Comment: Yes, the desiredAccuracy is only for standard location

Comment: One more question: Does significant change monitoring is supported on iPhone3 models? I read that region based monitoring is available only on iPhone4, just curious what about significant change?

Comment: It's available starting from iOS 4

Comment: What if i want to track whether user's current city got changed or not. i don't want location update for every 500m. its about few kilometers. How to configure this in significant location service?

Comment: @Geoffroy I was reading the documentation, and after reading your answer, I am still not clear about this method "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" that if it ignores the desiredAccuracy and distanceFilter then how much accuracy or after how much distance it notify us

Comment: @UsamaSadiq this post is 6.5 years old and I don't work on iOS anymore, I can just tell you it's when the change is "significant", as in "what's around you won't be much different if you walk 200 meters so it's not significant"

Comment: @Geoffroy Thanks